# Redirect "contact us" form to different email addresses

Tags: html, perl, email

I have a single contact-us form and what I would like to do is use this single form such as `contact.html` (not multiple copies of this form) everywhere on my website as my site has different contact-us sections based on the department.

Let's say the contact-us form for marketing should email to `marketing@mydomian.com`,  contact-us form for sales should email to `sales@mydomian.com`, HR's contact-us form should  email to `hr@mydomain.com`.

How can I use the single form while redirecting the submission to the appropriate department email address?

I am using FormMail.pl Version 3.14m1 for email submission.

Comment: There's lots of ways - base it on the URL, the page title, or an `input type="hidden"` value with a department ID to denote the intended recipient.

Answer (score 3):

In Example 4 of [this document](http://nms-cgi.sourceforge.net/formmail_modules-3.14m1/EXAMPLES) there's an explanation of how to do it if you can set a hidden field. This is probably the best solution.

---

If you want the same form for all the different parts of your website an `input type="hidden"` will not work. You'll have to check the referring URL.

You probably already have edited the configuration section of the perl script. This is what it looks like. You shouldn't change stuff further down than the end of this section.

```
# USER CONFIGURATION SECTION
# --------------------------
# Modify these to your own settings. You might have to
# contact your system administrator if you do not run
# your own web server. If the purpose of these
# parameters seems unclear, please see the README file.
#
BEGIN
{
```

You could still do the config like they did in the above mentioned example:

```
%recipient_alias   = (
   'hr' => 'hr@mydomain.com',
   'sales'  => 'sales@mydomian.com',
   'marketin' => 'marketing@mydomian.com',
);
```

However, if there is no hidden field then we will have to change things aroung a bit:

```
$ENV{'HTTP_REFERER'} =~ m!mydomain.com/(\w+)/contact\.html/!;
@recipients = ($recipient_alias{$1});
```

I've added a regular expression to find out which department's contact form the request came from. I'm asuming the URL looks like `http://www.mydomain.com/sales/contact.html`. The regex will catch the department and put it in `$1` where we can use it as a key to the `%recipient_alias` hash. We out the value of that key in the `@recipients` array.

I just assumed that this will be used if there is no hidden field for the alias. If it doesn't work you should change the name of the hash.

I've found the code for FormMail.pl [here](http://nms-cgi.sourceforge.net/formmail_modules-3.14m1/FormMail.pl). I hope it's the correct one.

Comment: thanks for the quick response. I will try  and let you know if its working

Comment: hi where this $ENV{'HTTP_REFERER'} =~ m!mydomain.com/(\w+)/contact\.html/!; @recipients = ($recipient_alias{$1}); part need to be inserted in the .pl file and how to do the condition for  each url. i am new in cgi- or perl.

Comment: Just put it where the `%recipient_alias` and the `@recipients` values are right now. Should be in the top half a little down from the `BEGIN` part I posted in the answer. **Don't edit below the config** if you don't know what you're doing, though.

Answer (score 0):

@Widor has offered a few suggestions in his comment and one of those may be best for you.

But I think it may be useful to check the `Referer` header to see which page the request came from. I imagine you will be able to determine an appropriate addressee from that.

Comment: how to use a refer, is there any example. i am new to perl